# Angular-bootstratp ui typeahead for no matching results

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Hi I am using bootstrap ui typeahead in my angularjs site. This works great. Just wondering whether it is possible to show some text like "No matches found" when the user type something that is not in the list.

Comment: The second [example](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) displays a message below the input when there are no matches. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The typeahead directive includes an attribute for this, typeahead-no-results.

Here is an example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Placeholder Text" typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
```

Then use ng-if or ng-show to display your error message.

```
<div ng-if="noResults">
  No Results Found!
</div>
```

For more reading material be sure to check out the [bootstrap-ui docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

Comment: You are correct. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This may go without saying, but if you have two or more Typeaheads on a page, setting up typeahead-no-results="noResults" will result in all of them showing. So, set up typeahead-no-results="noResultsA", typeahead-no-results="noResultsB", etc. if you want them to operate independently.

Comment: This built-in option works only in the when you have a single typeahead on the page. Otherwise, you have to work-around like I explained in the second answer.

Answer (score 1):

The **typeahead-no-results** option doesn't support multiple typeaheads and is quite clumsy in my opinion.
You probably want to display "No matches found" instead of the results and not somewhere else.

I was forced to make this very minor workaround to the UibTypeaheadController inside the method that is called upon selection:

```
scope.select = function(activeIdx, evt) {

    if (scope.matches.length === 1 
        && scope.matches[activeIdx].model != null 
        && scope.matches[activeIdx].model.noMatchesFound) {
        return;
    }
```

In addition you I had to push a dummy object when there were no matches in the search call back:

```
    if (matches.length === 0) {
        matches.push({ 
                      displayProperty: "No matches found", 
                      noMatchesFound: true 
                     });
    }
```